# How to perform intersect operations in the Field Calculator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, intersection

How to use the Intersect function?

How would I specify to

```
REPLACE layer1.field1 with layer2.field2 WHEN layer1.geometry INTERSECTS layer2.geometry
```

Is that feasible in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

No currently this is not possible in the field calculator.  The expression engine doesn't support any kind of joins like this currently.

On the todo list but needs a bit of work.

Comment: Is this possible in QGIS 3.x?